# How to iterate through multiple id's using while loop in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How to iterate through multiple id's using while loop in sql server and after every loop show error message

```
    DECLARE @InventoryId Int
Select @InventoryId = I.InventoryId
                 From G2owner.LoadSlip L (nolock)
                 Inner Join G2owner.LoadSlipReleaseOrderMapping LM (nolock) on L.LoadSlipID = LM.LoadSlipID
                 Inner Join G2owner.LoadSlipDetail LSD (nolock) on LM.LoadSlipReleaseOrdermappingID = LSD.LoadSlipReleaseOrdermappingID 
                 Inner Join G2owner.Inventory I (nolock) on LSD.InventoryID = I.InventoryID
                 Where LM.ReleaseOrderID = 7156 and L.LoadSlipID = 3014
                 and L.TerminalID = 3 and I.InventoryEndDate IS NULL and I.TotalNetWeight = 0.0000000
```

In this above query i will get list of inventory id's i need to loop through each and if inventory id exist then i need to print out some message

show error message as

```
    Select @arg_ErrorNo = @InventoryId
            Select @arg_ErrorMessage = 'Range release order for inventory  is shipped out.'
```

Comment: I think that you can use the SELECT   CASE and with this you don't need a loop.

Select case when I.InventoryId is not null then 'EXIST' else 'not exist' end
                 From

Comment: You do NOT need to use a loop for this kind of thing. Also, be careful littering your database with NOLOCK hints. You can and will get missing and/or duplicate data. It also present a whole myriad of other significant challenges and inaccurate data. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: print out a message how?   With a PRINT statement in SSMS?

Comment: it should be inventoryid as error number

Comment: Updated my question. Please suggest

Comment: Looks like there is no need to "loop through". If inventory id exists - it will be stored in @InventoryID variable right after this query. To loop through id values  - add order by InventoryID and select next top 1 each loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through list of ID's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347339/how-to-loop-through-list-of-ids)