# How to loop through list of ID's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting list of id's in the select statement. How to loop through each id and print below

```
DECLARE @InventoryID INT
Select @InventoryID = I.InventoryID
From G2owner.LoadSlip L (nolock)
     Inner Join G2owner.LoadSlipReleaseOrderMapping LM (nolock) on L.LoadSlipID = LM.LoadSlipID
     Inner Join G2owner.LoadSlipDetail LSD (nolock) on LM.LoadSlipReleaseOrdermappingID = LSD.LoadSlipReleaseOrdermappingID 
     Inner Join G2owner.Inventory I (nolock) on LSD.InventoryID = I.InventoryID
Where LM.ReleaseOrderID = 7156 and L.LoadSlipID = 3014
      and L.TerminalID = 3 and I.InventoryEndDate IS NULL and I.TotalNetWeight = 0.0000000

PRINT @InventoryID
```

Comment: What makes you think you need a loop?  Just use `Select I.InventoryID From ...`.

Comment: I need to loop because i need to use each invetoryID across multiple places in other stored procedure

Comment: You should really try to use set-based logic as much as possible, even if you're dumping the list of IDs to a temporary table.  However, if you insist that you must use a loop, you'd have to [use a cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856518/sql-server-2008-request-example-on-creating-a-cursor-to-loop-through-records) to do what you're describing.

Comment: [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: @BaconBits Using cursor for this performance is affected badly

Comment: No kidding performance is going to be badly affected.  That's why I said, "You should really try to use set-based logic as much as possible, even if you're dumping the list of IDs to a temporary table."  You say you **need** a loop.  That means cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid Cursors or any row by row operation which uses loops if you can as it hinders performance, but if you have to:

```
DECLARE @InventoryID INT

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT I.InventoryID
From G2owner.LoadSlip L with(nolock)
    Inner Join G2owner.LoadSlipReleaseOrderMapping LM with(nolock) on L.LoadSlipID = LM.LoadSlipID
    Inner Join G2owner.LoadSlipDetail LSD with(nolock) on LM.LoadSlipReleaseOrdermappingID = LSD.LoadSlipReleaseOrdermappingID 
    Inner Join G2owner.Inventory I with(nolock) on LSD.InventoryID = I.InventoryID
Where LM.ReleaseOrderID = 7156 and L.LoadSlipID = 3014
    and L.TerminalID = 3 and I.InventoryEndDate IS NULL and I.TotalNetWeight = 0.0000000

OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @InventoryID 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    PRINT (@InventoryID);
   FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @InventoryID
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Also `WITH(nolock)` can lead to dirty reads!!!

Comment: NOLOCK is so much more than just dirty reads. Honestly, dirty reads are insignificant compared to some of the things that can happen when using that hint. See the link @marc_s posted in the comments above for more details about all the nasty stuff that hint brings to the table.